# Attempt to call a nil value when changing an IntValue for leaderstats

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make an admin panel, everytime I want to change the value with a username
Code:

leaderstats Script;

```lua
--// Set up folder

local AdminModule = require(game:GetService('ServerScriptService').leaderstats.MainModule)
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new('Folder', plr)
    leaderstats.Name = 'leaderstats'
    
    local Playtime = Instance.new('IntValue', leaderstats)
    
    Playtime.Name = 'Playtime'
end)

AdminModule.GivePoints('happy_speler', 500)
```

MainModule:

```lua
local module = {
    GivePoints = function(plr, amount)
        plr:WaitForChild('leaderstats'):WaitForChild('Playtime').Value = amount
    end,
    
    
}

return module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have tried to call a function that doesn't exist.

Looking at the `AdminModule.GivePoints` function, it looks like it expects a Player object for the `plr` argument, but you have passed in a string. The string library does not have a `WaitForChild` function, so calling `plr:WaitForChild` is throwing the error.

The way to fix this is to properly pass in a Player object :

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ServerScriptService = game:GetService("ServerScriptService")
local AdminModule = require(ServerScriptService.leaderstats.MainModule)

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect( function(plr)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new('Folder', plr)
    leaderstats.Name = 'leaderstats'

    local Playtime = Instance.new('IntValue', leaderstats)
    Playtime.Name = 'Playtime'

    if plr.Name == 'happy_speler' then
        AdminModule.GivePoints(plr, 500)
    end
end)
```